# C# & ASP.NET MVC Razor - return checked items in list from view to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of objects (Client) displayed, with a property "Selected" shown in a checkbox which I would like to work with in the controller once submitted back. Everything works, except receiving the items back with the updated "Selected" property, I receive an empty list.

This is the  Client Class (Model):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime Alive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the code in the View (cleaned)

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Client>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendCommand", "Command", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <input type="text" name="command" />
           
    <button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
                 

        <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> 
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Selected)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientId)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alive)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alive)
                    </td>
                </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

And this is in the controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var clients = Clients.GetClients(); //<<this works, returns List of Client

    return View(clients);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SendCommand()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendCommand(string command, IEnumerable<Client> clients)
{
    // Here, command has the value entered in the input text command from the view
    foreach (Client c in clients)  // but here, clients is an empty list :(
    {
    }
      
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I've tried to name the checkboxes as `Model.Selected[ClientId]` following some other solutions but or I didn't do it properly or didn't work.

Some help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@*change foreach to for like this*@ 
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.ToList()[i].Selected)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(it => Model.ToList()[i].Selected)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ToList()[i].ClientId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(it => Model.ToList()[i].Name)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
```